# Can you customize route constraints in blazor routing

Tags: blazor, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have this strange construct where some of our domain objects have an ID based on an 18 character string. Is there a way to add a route constraint to match a string only if it matches a certain length / format?  As it stands, any string may be passed.

I know I can do it with "OnParameterSet" and check the parameter value, but I'd rather do it something like:

```
@page "/Account/{AccountSID:StringID}"
<h3>AccountDetails</h3>
<div>@AccountSID</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string AccountSID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: [no](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraints-1). It's [still on the backlog](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28938).

Comment: To answer your question  What's the else option i,e, what happens if ``AccountID` is not a 18 char string?

Comment: Do you want that the route responses of _exactly_ the number of characters you specify or do you want to manage a sort of exception on the invalid parameter format/length ?

Comment: Ideally, if not matched, should return 404.

Comment: Currently, use "OnParameterSet" or write your own router.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If you'll post that as the answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting Henk's answer:

No, currently not possible without writing a custom router...

use "OnParameterSet"